# Why does "grep" gives error when using /"/"?

Tags: bash, grep

### Background

I am trying to get the PID of a command that is executed using `sh -c` and store it within a variable for later use.

```
#!/bin/bash

execute() {
   CMDS="$1"

   # x-terminal-emulator executes the quoted text by executing 'sh -c "$CMDS"'
   # Which is why "ps ax | grep ..." is used to search for the PID that
   # matches "sh -c $CMDS"
   x-terminal-emulator -e "$CMDS" &> /dev/null 

   cmdsPID="$(ps ax | grep \"sh -c "$CMDS"\" | xargs | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"

   echo "$cmdsPID"
}

execute "apt full-upgrade -y"
```

### ⚠️ Error

However, upon executing the above script, it returns: `grep: apt full-upgrade -y": No such file or directory`, why?

Comment: @Tiw `$CMDS` takes in the first parameter of the function `execute` thus `apt full-upgrade -y`. `sh -c $CMDS`  simply launches a new shell executing the contents of the quotes within it and does not output an error.

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: As for the error: You are for some unknown reason escaping the quotes, making them non-quotes, and thus passing *three* arguments to `grep` (`"sh`, `-c` and `apt full-upgrade -y"`), telling it to count the number of `"sh`s in the file `apt full-upgrade -y"`, and it’s telling you it can’t find that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I apparently was overthinking the fact that I needed to escape the quotes for it to work. However, that is exactly what I should not do! I simply just need the quotes unescaped and it works.

This is because, as [@biffen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418066/biffen) pointed out:

"*As for the error: You are for some unknown reason escaping the quotes, making them non-quotes, and thus passing three arguments to grep ("`sh`, `-c` and `apt full-upgrade -y"`), telling it to count the number of "`sh`'s in the file `apt full-upgrade -y"`, and it’s telling you it can’t find that file.*"

```
#!/bin/bash

execute() {
    CMDS="$1"

    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # x-terminal-emulator executes the quoted text by executing 'sh -c "$CMDS"'
    # Which is why "ps ax | grep ..." is used to search for the PID that
    # matches "sh -c $CMDS"
    x-terminal-emulator -e "$CMDS" &> /dev/null 

    cmdsPID="$(ps ax | grep -v "grep" | grep -v "S+" | grep "sh -c" | grep "$CMDS" | xargs | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"

    echo "$cmdsPID"
}

execute "apt full-upgrade -y"
```

Comment: idk what you're using `xargs` for at all but you don't need multiple greps and pipes and cuts, etc to just get a pid from any ps output and inclding a `grep -v grep` is definitely not the right approach to rule out the grep itself. If you post a new question showing the `ps` output you're trying to get the pid from them we can help you. It's also not clear what you're hoping `&> /dev/null` will do (as opposed to, say, `> /dev/null &` or `2>/dev/null`).

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for your input. I appreciate your thoughts. If you find my answer insufficient, then please provide and alternative response. Thanks.

Comment: I can't because you haven't provided sample input (i.e. the output of `ps ax`) and expected output for what I was addressing my my comment. As I mentioned, if you'd like help with what I commented on then ask a new question about that.